# sql: get a single-column table, order by column from another table

Tags: sql, cs50

I have interconnected tables.

```
movies (main, parent) : id | title | year
people (child) : people_id | name | birthyear
ratings (child) : movie_id | rating | votes
stars (child) : movie_id | person_id
```

I need to make a query ang get a sinle column output from tables "movies-people-stars" and order that by column from the table "rating" without joining column "rating" to my output.

My code:

```
SELECT title from movies
where id in (select movie_id from stars
         where person_id in(select id from people where name = "Chadwick Boseman"))LIMIT 5;
```

It returns all titles of movies where Chadwick Boseman plays. I need to order them by rating. How to do it?

Comment: You need to include the column in the select list to order by that column. order by sorts your output in the order of the column you specify. Also, why can't you use JOINs for your query.

Comment: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/7/movies/ - 11.sql - one column ordered by rating

Comment: `one column ordered by rating` does not mean 'you must not use a join' :). In future please do not interpret such requirements/restrictions, instead state/quote the problem to be solved.

Comment: With the information given, how do you think people can help you???  "I need to build one column query from tables "a-c" and order that by column from the table "d" without joining table "d" to mine".  Why can't you join to table "d"?  I don't see table "a", "b", "c", "d" in your query.

Comment: Please read this to learn how to ask a question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Now it may be more clear

Answer (score 2):

Although this would never be done without a join, since it is homework, you can use a correlated subquery for the table `ratings` in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select m.title
from movies m
inner join stars s on s.movie_id = m.id
inner join people p on p.people_id = s.person_id
where p.name = 'Chadwick Boseman'
order by (select r.rating from ratings r where r.movie_id = m.id) desc
limit 5
```

You could also use your query and add the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select m.title 
from movies m
where m.id in (
  select movie_id 
  from stars
  where person_id in(
    select id 
    from people 
    where name = 'Chadwick Boseman'
  )
)
order by (select r.rating from ratings r where r.movie_id = m.id) desc
limit 5;
```

Comment: the 'no join' restriction seems to be a misunderstanding, at least there is no mention of that in the source-question the OP linked to here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62454269/sql-order-by-column-from-another-table-without-join#comment110454264_62454269 - https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/7/movies/ . +1 for answering the question as asked anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the column in the select list to order by that column. Order by sorts your output in the order of the column you specify. Also, why can't you use JOINs for your query like below.

```
SELECT m.title,d.rating 
FROM movies m
JOIN stars s ON s.movie_id = m.id
JOIN people p ON p.id = s.person_id 
JOIN tbl d ON d.xx = z.yy  ----- JOIN the table d here and use it in select . replace z,xx and yy with actual table name and columns.
WHERE p.name = "Chadwick Boseman" 
ORDER BY d.rating
LIMIT 5
```

updated* - It might work but not able to test as I don't have access to actual data and tables.

```
SELECT m.title
FROM movies m
JOIN stars s ON s.movie_id = m.id
JOIN people p ON p.id = s.person_id
WHERE p.name = 'Chadwick Boseman'
AND m.id in (SELECT top 5 movie_id 
             FROM ratings r
             WHERE r.movie_id = m.id 
             ORDER BY ratings desc)
```

Comment: I can`t because as a solution for this task I need to return only "title" column but order it by ratings.rating without joining ratings

Comment: As I understood for myself, "join" means something "add another column to existing ones and output the result" - turns out ... it doesn`t...

Comment: `You need to include the column in the select list to order by that column` - this is not true. @Hedgehog please edit the question to reflect the _actual_ problem you wanted to solve.